# What dragons do I need to complete the "Every Last One" achievement?

Tags: achievements, dragonvale

The achievement text says:

> Possess every dragon in DragonVale... all at once.

What is the complete list of dragon breeds needed?  I'm hoping that limited dragons aren't included, since that would make this achievement impossible at this point. I'm also interested to know if dragons in the Hibernation Cave count towards this achievement.

Comment: I mistakenly rolledback a retag on this one.  Apologize for the bump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Limited dragons are most certainly *not* included, I got the achievement without having the Bone dragon, and I also didn't have a Plant dragon at the time either, so I think it only tracks whether you've *ever* had the dragons, despite the description.

There's lots of speculation on the [Wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Achievements) and it seems like some people just aren't getting the achievement, but it might be due to game center being laggy or something.

It appears to be the case that you need all non-limited dragons, **including rare dragons** like the Rainbow Dragon. This doesn't include limited dragons that are currently available; only year-round dragons count, but you need all that are currently available. It seems this is a moving goalpost, meaning as new year-round dragons are added, those are added to the requirement.

Comment: Did you have a hibernation cave at the time?  Any idea if that plays a role?

Comment: @EBongo Hibernation caves didn't exist then. They SHOULD count toward your total but I haven't found any evidence supporting or refuting that.

Comment: If I had been more careful, I could confirm the hibernation cave angle. I can confirm that it requires all non-limited dragons, because I got it immediately upon hatching a Quicksilver, which was only just added.

Comment: @EBongo really? So you had every other kind of non-limited dragon up to that point?

Comment: Yep, including rares.  I got the Forge off the bat the day it was announced by luck, since I happened to be breeding that pair.  I had been trying to breed Frostfire forever and finally Googled it and found a good pair.  I've several times been down to just FrostFire, but they keep adding dragons!  Well, I caught up to them finally.

Comment: @EBongo updated my answer. I really didn't expect that; the achievement is now twice as hard as it was when I got it, and it's worth the same points!

Comment: Yeah, it certainly seems a harder acheivement for new comers vs. vets.  They probably don't mind that though.  If anything it encourages folks to spend gems, which can equate to real money for them.